# Will componentWillMount run again if component is re-rendered because of parent component?

Tags: reactjs

Will `componentWillMount` run again if component is re-rendered because of parent component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, componentWillMount is called only once.

Also, componentDidMount is called only once.

componentDidUpdate is called on every re-render.

To correctly understand about the react lifecycle methods you can go through this link.
https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1

Comment: componentWillMount called once while component is mounting for the first time. Try to avoid using of componentWillMount, componentWillReceiveProps and componentWillUpdate. Because it is going to be deprecated in react future version.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**
It's called once right before your component is about to be rendered to the `DOM`.

*The long answer is:*

**componentWillMount**
Your component is going to appear on the screen very shortly. That chunky render function, with all its beautifully off-putting JSX, is about to be called.
Most Common Use Case: App configuration in your root component.
Can call setState: Yes, but don't. Use the default state instead.

---

**componentDidMount**
Here is where you load in your data. ComponentDidMount is also where you can do all the fun things you couldn’t do when there was no component to play with. Basically, here you want to do all the setup you couldn’t do without a DOM, and start getting all the data you need. Most Common Use Case: Starting AJAX calls to load in data for your component.

---

**componentWillReceiveProps**
Perhaps some data that was loaded in by a parent component’s componentDidMount finally arrived and is being passed down. Before our component does anything with the new props, componentWillReceiveProps is called, with the next props as the argument.

---

**shouldComponentUpdate**
shouldComponentUpdate should always return a boolean — an answer to the question, “should I re-render?” Yes, little component, you should. The default is that it always returns true. It's an awesome place to improve performance.

---

**componentWillUpdate**
Most Common Use Case: Used instead of componentWillReceiveProps on a component that also has shouldComponentUpdate (but no access to previous props). It’s basically the same as componentWillReceiveProps, except you are not allowed to call this.setState.

---

**componentDidUpdate**
Here we can do the same stuff we did in componentDidMount — reset our masonry layout, redraw our canvas, etc. Basically, we use it when it's all said and done, but we don’t want to waste time to redraw the canvas every time it updates. Most Common Use Case: Updating the DOM in response to prop or state changes.

---

**componentWillUnmount**
Here you can cancel any outgoing network requests, or remove all event listeners associated with the component. Basically, clean up anything to do that solely involves the component in question — when it’s gone, it should be completely gone.